# I have some coarse ground Espresso and a Bodum French press

Tags: espresso

Is it possible to make espresso in a Bodum French press coffee machine?

Unfortunately, the Espresso beans were ground coarse instead of fine.

Answer (score 1):

## No

There is no way of brewing espresso with a french press.
Es**press**o is brewed under **press**ure, typically 9-10 bars.
You cannot achieve this level of pressure no matter which brand your french press has.

Additionally, the TDS (total dissolved solids) of espresso [is around 8-12 while for french press coffee it's 1.4-1.7](https://fellowproducts.com/blogs/learn/the-beginner-s-guide-to-total-dissolved-solids-and-coffee).

However, you can get a cup of coffee which has more texture and a fuller body than filter coffee by [grinding finer and increasing your dose](https://www.baristahustle.com/wp-content/uploads/images/products/products-Coffee-Compass-1024x1024.jpg). It won't come anywhere near espresso but it's not as "watery" as filter coffee. Being able to adjust your recipe for taste like this is one of the many advantages of buying your coffee in beans and grinding them before use.

Comment: Grinding finer then the coarse grind that is optimum for a french press will result in a lesser quality cup of coffee, and there is no reason to do it.

Comment: @AlaskaMan That is not true. Grind size is one of the first thing you adjust to change the taste of your cup of coffee. It has absolutely nothing to do with the quality. Grinding finer DOES NOT decrease the quality of your cup of coffee.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers may not be responding to the question you asked.

Beans are sometimes marketed as "espresso blends" based on the roasting quality (usually quite dark) and origin blends. Of course, preground espresso blends typically are sold very finely ground--perfect for espresso machines.

If your "espresso blend" was ground coarsely enough to be used in a French press, yes, you can brew it in the French press. Of course the resulting brew will not taste like espresso. It will taste like French press with a dark roast. Your mileage may vary depending on the actual fineness of the grind (i.e., it may not actually be fine enough for French press even if it is much to coarse for espresso).

Answer (score 0):

Espresso is an emulsion.  That makes it quite different from other coffee preparations, which are simply extractions.  The only way to achieve that emulsion is with the proper grind and using a machine specifically designed to force water through it, to make espresso.  Espresso can be made with many different types of beans.

Conversely, drip, pour-over, and french press coffee can be made with espresso beans.  It can be delicious.  In fact, I use espresso beans for my pour over coffee.  It just isn't espresso.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds as though you've accidentally happened upon the materials for a perfect cup of coffee.  'Espresso beans', as noted above, refers mainly to the roast (a longer, darker one that yields a fuller flavour, more body, low acidity, and slighty less caffeine, which is degraded by the extra heat), though an 'espresso blend' may also be heavier on robusta and lighter on arabica, as the latter's acids and aromas are also sensitive to longer thermal exposure.  Coarse grinds are actually the most appropriate for French presses.  An 'espresso grind' (super-fine, second only to Turkish) would clog the mesh and make a muddy confection that is, well, not what the designers of French presses had in mind.  So you've got nice, user-friendly tech, the right grind for it, and a tasty roast.  Espresso is made with espresso machines, but great coffee has no limits on the sorts of equipment from which it is willing to emerge.